# How to view local storage Docs, PPT and excel files within flutter application?

Tags: excel, flutter, powerpoint, documentation, viewer

I'm creating a document viewer offline app in Flutter. Flutter provides numerous pdf packages to view pdf.
But I'm unable to find any of the other files (Docs, ppt, excel) viewer package or any free third-party SDK.
As this app works offline, I cannot use any sort of API either.
I've got all the files from the device and can use the file path to display the document

I've tried flutter_file_preview, power_file_viewer, and other packages to display files within the app, but these packages have issues and couldn't work anymore.
This app will work offline so I cannot upload the to Firebase and get the file URL to display in Webview.

Comment: I am also looking solution for it